# How to set number of output files per reducer in Custom Partioner

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have to generate more number of output files inside particular  Reducer output.
I have implemented custom partioner that directs output data into respective reducer .But some of my reducer have more that 20 gb data and some has only 15 mb of data .Now my issue is how to create small output files inside reducer that will have 20 gb of data .Like in one reducer 5 small output files so data processing in reducer phase will be faster .

I googled and found i have to use MultiOutput for my problem .But i am confused hot to use .
Please suggest some implementation .

I am reading data from HBase and writing to text files .

Here is my driver code

```
Job job = new Job(hbaseConf);
    job.setJarByClass(HBaseToFileDriver.class);
    job.setJobName("Importing Data from HBase to File:::" + args[0]);

    Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.setFilter(new RowFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL, new SubstringComparator("Japan")));
    scan.setCaching(10000); // 1 is the default in Scan, which will be bad
                // for
                // MapReduce jobs
    scan.setCacheBlocks(false); // don't set to true for MR jobs
    scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes("cf"));

    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(args[0], // input table
        scan, // Scan instance to control CF and attribute selection
        MyMapper.class, // mapper class
        Text.class, // mapper output key
        IntWritable.class, // mapper output value
        job);
    job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class); // reducer class
    job.setPartitionerClass(MyPartioner.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(6); // at least one, adjust as required
    //job.setInt("outputs.per.reducer", 4);

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
```

Here is my Mapper Code

```
public class MyMapper extends TableMapper<Text, IntWritable> {

    private final IntWritable ONE = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text text = new Text();



    public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String FundamentalSeriesId = new String(value.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("FundamentalSeriesId")));
    String FundamentalSeriesId_objectTypeId = new String(value.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("FundamentalSeriesId_objectTypeId")));

    text.set(FundamentalSeriesId+"|^|"+FundamentalSeriesId_objectTypeId+"|!|");

    context.write(text, ONE);
    }
}
```

This is my partioner

```
public class MyPartioner extends Partitioner<Text, IntWritable> {

    public int getPartition(Text key, IntWritable value, int setNumRedTask) {

    String str = key.toString();
    if (str.contains("Japan|2014")) {
        return 0;
    } else if (str.contains("Japan|2013")) {
        return 1;
    }  else if (str.contains("Japan|2012")) {
        return 2;
    } else if (str.contains("Japan|2011")) {
        return 3;
    } else if (str.contains("Japan|2010")) {
        return 4;
    }

        return 5;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to emit only 6 reducers and if you want to distribute the data based on the Year, then based on the data characteristic, it will happen that some reducer will have 20Gb while some will have only 15Mb to process.

And in case if you use MultipleOutputFormat and if the same is the senerio where you are distributing the data for 6 buckets, then you will land to the same page.

Either you can find another attribute like Year and other attribute or you have to increase the reducer count and have to define partitioner based on attribute's HashCode(Again in that case also it might happen few reducer will get more data for processing).

You can find a MultipleOutput example at below link if you just want to refer,

http://hadooptutorial.info/mapreduce-multiple-outputs-use-case/